# flask form "_l" symbol meaning

Tags: python, flask, notifications

I am trying to implement a form in my flask web app. Following [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxi-user-notifications) I found this form:

```py
class MessageForm(FlaskForm):
    message = TextAreaField(_l('Message'), validators=[
        DataRequired(), Length(min=0, max=140)])
    submit = SubmitField(_l('Submit'))
```

but if I try to put it in my app it tells me:

```py
message = TextAreaField(_l('Message'), validators=[

NameError: name '_l' is not defined
```

Can somebody help with that? I tried to search the web and this blog but I did not find a definition of the symbol and why my machine does not recognize it.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely internationalisation-related utils.

`from flask_babel import lazy_gettext as _l` at the top should do the trick.

Reference from the same tutorial [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xiii-i18n-and-l10n)